# How to convert Firebase timestamp to local date in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, next.js

I'm trying to convert Firebase timestamp to local date without success.
I'm getting `Invalid Date` with the code below. What am I doing wrong with `toLocaleString` or is there other methods?

```
<Table.Header>
  <Table.Column>Email</Table.Column>
  <Table.Column>Last login</Table.Column>
  <Table.Column>Created</Table.Column>
</Table.Header>
<Table.Body>
  {usersList.map((user, index) => (
    <Table.Row key={index}>
      <Table.Cell>{user.user.email}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{new Date(user.user.lastLoginAt).toLocaleString("da-DK", {year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit",})}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{new Date(user.user.createdAt).toLocaleString("da-DK", {year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit",})}</Table.Cell>
    </Table.Row>
  ))}
</Table.Body>
```

Comment: is the data fetched server-side or client-side?

Comment: What are the values for `user.user.lastLoginAt` and `user.user.createdAt`?

Comment: @juliomalves It shows a number like this on both: 1658828001030

Comment: @mocherfaoui client side.

Comment: @juliomalves When I console log the 'usersList' (useState) where the data is stored it shows data correctly just like in firebase: https://i.gyazo.com/cf480a4a6eb787fae005ee04efd4cc1e.png - but when i call user.user.lastLoginAt as shown above in the map loop it says 'Invalid date'. E: Also the user.user.email shows correctly as shown above, so Idk what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because both `lastLoginAt` and `createdAt` values come as strings from your API data. You need to convert them to a number so they can be used inside the `new Date()` call.

```js
new Date(Number(user.user.lastLoginAt))
new Date(Number(user.user.createdAt))
```

The [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#parameters) expects the timestamp value to be a number.

> **Time value or timestamp number**
>
> `value`
>
> An integer value representing the number of milliseconds since January
> 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC (the ECMAScript epoch, equivalent to the UNIX
> epoch), with leap seconds ignored. Keep in mind that most [UNIX
> Timestamp](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_16) functions are only accurate to the nearest second.